# Transfer String from viewcontroller1 to viewcontroller2 and show barcode scan(String) in textbox of uiwebview

Tags: ios, objective-c, barcode

I have a barcodescanner in one viewcontroller and a uiwebview in a second viewcontroller. How can i get the string which was created in the first viewcontroller catch in the second viewcontroller. I tried several things and tested it with nslog but it always shows me (nil) for the string value. Help me please out of this.

Here is my code:

igViewController.m:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import "igViewController.h"
#import "ViewController.h"


@interface igViewController () <AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate>
{
    AVCaptureSession *_session;
    AVCaptureDevice *_device;
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *_input;
    AVCaptureMetadataOutput *_output;
    AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *_prevLayer;

    UIView *_highlightView;
   }
@end

@implementation igViewController
@synthesize detectionString;
@synthesize delegate;
@synthesize thedetected;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _highlightView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    _highlightView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
    _highlightView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
    _highlightView.layer.borderWidth = 3;
    [self.view addSubview:_highlightView];

    _label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    _label.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height - 40, self.view.bounds.size.width, 40);
    _label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
    _label.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.15 alpha:0.65];
    _label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    _label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    _label.text = @"(nichts)";
    [self.view addSubview:_label];

    _session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    _device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    NSError *error = nil;

    _input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:_device error:&error];
    if (_input) {
        [_session addInput:_input];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }

    _output = [[AVCaptureMetadataOutput alloc] init];
    [_output setMetadataObjectsDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    [_session addOutput:_output];

    _output.metadataObjectTypes = [_output availableMetadataObjectTypes];

    _prevLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:_session];
    _prevLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
    _prevLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:_prevLayer];

    [_session startRunning];

    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:_highlightView];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:_label];


}
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    if(detectionString!=nil){

        UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *top = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;

        UIViewController *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Controller1"];
        [top presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
    }

}


- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputMetadataObjects:(NSArray *)metadataObjects fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
    CGRect highlightViewRect = CGRectZero;
    AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *barCodeObject;
    detectionString = nil;
    NSArray *barCodeTypes = @[AVMetadataObjectTypeUPCECode, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Mod43Code,
            AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN8Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode93Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode128Code,
            AVMetadataObjectTypePDF417Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode, AVMetadataObjectTypeAztecCode];

    for (AVMetadataObject *metadata in metadataObjects) {
        for (NSString *type in barCodeTypes) {
            if ([metadata.type isEqualToString:type])
            {
                barCodeObject = (AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *)[_prevLayer transformedMetadataObjectForMetadataObject:(AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *)metadata];
                highlightViewRect = barCodeObject.bounds;
                detectionString = [(AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *)metadata stringValue];
                setSomeNumber:[(AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *)metadata stringValue];
                break;
            }
        }

        if (detectionString != nil)
        {
            _label.text = detectionString;
          // ViewController *otherViewController=[[ViewController alloc] init];

            UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
            UIViewController *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Controller1"];
            ViewController *otherViewController=[[ViewController alloc] init];

            [otherViewController barcodeverarbeiten:detectionString];
            NSLog(@"detectionstringssssss %@", detectionString);

            [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];


            break;
        }
        else
            _label.text = @"(nichts)";
    }

    _highlightView.frame = highlightViewRect;
}
- (void)setSomeNumber:(NSString *)tempString {
    _label.text = tempString;
}
-(NSString *) thedetected{


    return _label.text;
}

@end
```

ViewController.m (only webViewDidFinishLoad

```
-(void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)awebView{
        NSLog(@"detectionstring %@", otherViewController1.thedetected);
        if(otherViewController1.thedetected != nil){ //denk an self. ... bei igviewcontroller


        [self.Webseite stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByName('SEARCH_STRING_CONTENT')[0].value = '%@';",otherViewController1.thedetected]];
    NSString *evalStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"setTimeout( function(){document.getElementsByName(SEARCH_STRING_CONTENT')[0].focus();},1000);"];
    [self.Webseite stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:evalStr];

    [self.Webseite stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByClassName('buttonLinks searchButton withValue')[0].click();"];

    }
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
            if ([awebView canGoBack] == YES){
        [backButton setEnabled:YES];
    }else{
        [backButton setEnabled:NO];
    }
    if([awebView canGoForward] == YES){
        [forwardButton setEnabled:YES];
    }else{
        [forwardButton setEnabled:NO];
    }

}
```

igViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class ViewController;
@interface igViewController : UIViewController{
    ViewController *delegate;
@public
UILabel *_label;
    NSString *detectionString;
    //NSString *tempString;

}
@property (nonatomic, strong)NSString *detectionString;
@property (nonatomic, strong) ViewController *delegate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *thedetected;
//@property (nonatomic, strong)NSString *tempString;
- (void)setSomeNumber:(NSString *)tempString;
@end
```

ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "FavoritenController.h"
@class igViewController;


@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UIWebViewDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate>

{


    UIWebView *Webseite;
    UIBarButtonItem *backButton;
    UIBarButtonItem *forwardButton;
    UITextField *textField;
    UIBarButtonItem *refreshButton;
    NSString* urlBeforeEditing;
    UIBarButtonItem *barcodescan;
    igViewController *otherViewController1;

    FavoritenController* favoritenController;
           /* ..*/

}
@property  (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *barcodescan;

@property (nonatomic, strong)     igViewController *otherViewController1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *onlinetauscher;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *Webseite;
@property ( nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *refreshButton;
@property ( nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *backButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *forwardButton;
- (IBAction)onlinetauscher:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender;

- (IBAction)pressRefresh:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender;
//- (IBAction)search:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)zeigeMedikamente:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)hinzufuegen:(id)sender;
- (void)barcodeverarbeiten:(NSString*)barcodepzn;
@end
```

Comment: have you used property?

Comment: please upload .h file

Comment: ok, I uploaded the .h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it's working now. I used the NSUserDefaults to pass the String and catched it in my other ViewController. Cheers